# Nuxt 3 build on Vercel, fails when using route middleware

Tags: deployment, build, nuxt.js, vercel, netlify

I am raising this question just to bring awareness to this problem.

I created two middlewares for one of my projects and when deploying on Vercel, the build would fail. It worked perfectly fine on development and everything was done according to the documentation but the problem persisted.

While trying to figure this out I noticed that this happened only when I had **more than one middleware**. I still don't have a proper solution, but if anyone is having this issue, you can try using one middleware and have your whole logic there.

Netlify had the same issue.

Comment: Some actual code or [repro] would heavily help.

Comment: I just noticed a stupid mistake, the problem was with the naming, I should have used kebab-case, I had this middleware named hasBusiness, and when defining it should be has-business instead of hasBusiness. @kissu thanks for trying to help